no matching function while using a lambda function
template <typename T> class BinaryTree {
    ...

public:

    void traversal(void (*callback)(T &, int layer),
                   Order o = Order::preOrder) {
        _nodeTraversal(_root, callback, 0, o);
    }

    void traversal(void (*callback)(const T &, int layer),
                   Order o = Order::preOrder) const {
        _nodeTraversal(_root, callback, 0, o);
    }

    template <typename E>
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const BinaryTree<E> &bt);
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const BinaryTree<T> &bt) {
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    bt.traversal([&os](const T &elem, int layer) {
        for (int i = 0; i < layer; i++) {
            os << "    ";
        }
        os << elem << std::endl;
    });
    return os;
}

It throws an error when I compile this:
no matching function for call to 'BinaryTree<int>::traversal(operator<< <int>(std::ostream&, const BinaryTree<int>&)::<lambda(const int&, int)>) const' at the call of bt.traversal(). When I use [](...) {} (empty capture) with all os replaced by std::cout, it works. Why this happens and how do I solve it?

A lambda with captures is NOT convertible to a function pointer. If you want to support lambdas with captures use std::function<void(T&, int)> for your callbacks instead.

Lambda with captures cannot be converted to function pointer. You already know templates, make traversal and _nodeTraversal accept a template callable and you can call it a day.

Thanks for anwsering! They help with the problem.
